# I am trying to set image in imageView with absolute path of the image on my PC

Tags: android

```
try {
    File imgFile = new File("C:\\imageedit_7_6497580408.png");
    Bitmap imgBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
    imageView.setImageBitmap(imgBitmap);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is the error
E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /C:\imageedit_7_6497580408.png (No such file or directory)

I want to set image in imageView, but with absolute path of the image from my PC. I dont want to use emulator gallery, I want to take the image from my PC

Comment: You can't do that - the virtual device has no idea it's running on a PC, it doesn't know what `C:` is and doesn't have any way to access it. You either need to store your files in the virtual device's filesystem, package them with your app in *resources* or *assets*, or share them over the network so your app can access them with a URL

Comment: @hasan You need to learn android studio before getting started.

Comment: @M DEV thx for the info, I bet as a no android developer, I have developed more complex projects unlike you

Answer (score 0):

copy the image in drawable folder.

Comment: But I dont want to move it in drawable folder, because I use it from other app and I want to use it from local folder

Comment: @hasan, what do you consider to be a local folder? Local to what? Your pc is at home and you are with your Android app on your Android device in town. What is local?

Comment: its a uni project bro, that need only to work, its not a instragram or twitter. I dont need clear code, I only want to work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).